# Solving "Traveling Purchaser Problem"

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, travelling-salesman

Till now, I was using PostGIS-pgrouting `pgr_tsp` function to solve `Travelling Salesman Problems`. This function can give us the best possible route depending upon the `cost` parameter when the starting, finishing and via points are given.

But soon I realized to make my function more flexible. For example, in `pgr_tsp` function you provide the starting and finishing points along with the `via` points. But what if I am not sure about the exact `via` point? If I want to calculate the route starting from my home and going to the office via McDonald Restaurant and Shopping Mall, I am not explicitly defining which McDonald or which Shopping Mall? All I want is my route going from the Home to the Office via atleast one McDonald and one Shopping Mall; and has to be the shortest one depending upon the `cost` parameter I am using (`cost` parameter could be road length or travel time).

Literature reviews suggested me that `Traveling Purchaser Problem` is what I am looking for and `Travelling Salesman Problem` is a special case of this problem.

How can I solve the above explained `Traveling Purchaser Problem` in PostGIS? I came across the [jsprit](http://jsprit.github.io/) open source toolkit (a java based product) and [MATsim](http://www.matsim.org/) and these [other projects](https://github.com/jsprit/jsprit/wiki/Other-Projects), but I have no idea how to use them? Am I supposed to write a `PL/Java` procedural function to implement this `jsprit` toolkit in my PostGIS Db or what?

Any initial hint could jet propel from progress.

Answer (score 1):

jsprit and MATSim are open source Java projects. They do not use PostGIS database, but have their own datastructures they use for networks/graphs which are persisted in XML files.
If you think about using them to solve your problem, you would need to convert your network you have in your PostGIS database into the MATSim XML format. This conversion would need to be made manually somehow, at least there is no converter around I know of.

Comment: I have OSM data (which is an XML format data) as my road network in the PostGIS Db. Still need to convert the road network into MATSim XML format?

Comment: yes,  you need to convert it because the formats are different. But there are tools to directly convert OSM-XML to MATSim-XML: http://www.matsim.org/docs/tutorials/8lessons/input/creating/network gives an example on how this can be done.

Comment: Thx, I'll go through it.